# Expand nested JSONB data in SELECT query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Assuming I have a table with JSONB data:

```sql
create table x (
  id integer primary key generated always as identity,
  name text,
  data jsonb
);
```

Assuming data can have nested data, I would like to display all data inside data to have this kind of result:

```
id  name  data.a  data.b.0  data.b.1  data.c
1   test  1       foo       bar       baz
2   test2 789     pim       pam       boom
```

Is there a way to do this without specifying all the JSONB properties names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONB_TO_RECORDSET()` function might be used within such a Select statement

```
SELECT a AS "data.a", 
      (b::JSONB) ->> 0 AS "data.b.0", (b::JSONB) ->> 1 AS "data.b.1",
       c AS "data.c"
  FROM x, 
       JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(data) AS j(a INT, b TEXT, c TEXT)
 ORDER BY id
```

Presuming you have such JSONB values in the data column

```
[ { "a": 1, "b": ["foo","bar"], "c": "baz" }]
[ { "a": 789, "b": ["pim","pam"], "c": "boom" }]
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63b46d3b35f98ed730f7f2554a64228d)</kbd>